# Old MVC templates missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-1.0

I have updated my Visual Studio to MVC 6 or ASP.NET Core 1.0. When I am trying to make new project with MVC 5 it is unable to find the old MVC 5 templates, it only sees empty templates.

How to resolve this problem and get or add MVC 5 templates?

[image]